# AWS Question related with port (When a port is opened but connection is not possible)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I opened a port in aws, but when I run the 'netstat -tpnl' command in Ubuntu, the ports other than port 22 do not appear. What is the problem?

Below image is a port list in my EC2 instance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGPNp.png)

and netstat -tnlp command running in console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tA0M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html) (SGs) are independent from your operating system. Think about security groups as a **bubble** in which you place your instance. Your operating system is not aware that it is in this bubble.

Thus, when you open up ports in SGs, you make holes in this bubble. Only after you incoming connections enter the bubble, they can reach your instance. And then these connections can be visible in the operating system's networking tools.

Comment: so when you add 0.0.0.0/0, you burst the bubble?

Comment: @Asdfg Yes, if you also open up all ports, then all incoming traffic is allowed. But this is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: lol. I know. I was just making a joke on your bubble analogy.

Comment: @Asdfg I see. No problem.

Comment: Thank you for the easy to understand explanation. But I'm really an outsider, so how can I make the connection?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer. The ssh connection has already been established, but other port numbers cannot be connected (5000, 5050). I wonder why the other ports can't be connected. Thank you.

Comment: @Normalbut_Genuine Do you have any servers running that listen on these ports?